# Informatica PowerCenter - Stored procedure transformation doesn't return anything

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, informatica-powercenter

I have a problem in my mapping.

I have 8 objects:

- 1x Source table
- 1x Source qualifier reading from the Oracle DB
- 1x Expression Transformation that creates a JSON
- 1x Stored Procedure Transformation that should execute a stored procedure from SQL-Server with input the JSON from the previous Expression Transformation and output a new JSON
- 1x Filter Transformation that excludes the record in case the JSON returned by the previous Stored Procedure Transformation is null
- 1x Expression Transformation that takes all the information and prepares the call to the API
- 1x Http transformation that will send the json to Azure Search.
- 1x Destination file

Now, the problem is that the Stored Procedure Transformation does not return anything.
I have tried perform the procedure directly on the SQL Server db and it works.
Why doesn't Stored Procedure Transformation return anything?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are about five ways to return something from a stored procedure. Are you using the right method (the ways are: rowcount message, print message, select data, return parameter, return value). I suggest you check informatica doco to see. Also it wouldn't hurt to post the proc source code here

Comment: Check the db user which is connecting to oracle db from infa. Check input to oracle proc if its passed into correctly. Be careful if you are using parameters etc. Check if db is using some in built parameters/ other procedures. Run in verbose mode to see more in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the stored procedure on SQL Server.
I made a mock stored procedure that return a JSON and it works.